# No response of (ogc) "Sensor Observation Service" request from server

Tags: database, request, response, ogc

I am trying to make a "registerSensor" request. See the following xml file.
But unfortunately i only get an exception, about an NULL GET request. 
What confuse me the most is the fact that i send and read by POST method.

I know that probabely this issue doesn't fit to that forum, but i don't know where else to look for.... (would be even glad if you just give any advice, beside the ogc dokus)

I tested it twice on my own server and also at: http: //giv-sos.uni-muenster.de: 8080/52nSOSv3/

My request:

```
        <RegisterSensor 
    service="SOS" 
    version="1.0.0"
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sos/1.0"
    xmlns:swe="http://www.opengis.net/swe/1.0.1"
    xmlns:ows="http://www.opengeospatial.net/ows"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:om="http://www.opengis.net/om/1.0"
    xmlns:sml="http://www.opengis.net/sensorML/1.0.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sos/1.0"    
    http://schemas.opengis.net/sos/1.0.0/sosRegisterSensor.xsd http://www.opengis.net/om/1.0
    http://schemas.opengis.net/om/1.0.0/extensions/observationSpecialization_override.xsd>

  <SensorDescription>
  <sml:SensorML version="1.0.1">
  <sml:member>
  <sml:System xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   >
    <sml:identification>
    <sml:IdentifierList>
      <sml:identifier>
      <sml:Term definition="urn:ogc:def:identifier:OGC:uniqueID">

        <sml:value>Test Sensor1</sml:value>
        </sml:Term>
      </sml:identifier>
      </sml:IdentifierList>
    </sml:identification>
    <sml:capabilities>
    <swe:SimpleDataRecord> 
      <swe:field name="status">
        <swe:Boolean>
      <swe:value>true</swe:value>
      </swe:Boolean>
      </swe:field>
      <!-- status indicates, whether sensor is mobile (true) or fixed (false) -->
      <swe:field name="mobile">
        <swe:Boolean>
          <swe:value>true</swe:value>
        </swe:Boolean>
      </swe:field>
    </swe:SimpleDataRecord>
    </sml:capabilities>
    <sml:position name="sensorPosition">
    <swe:Position referenceFrame="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326">
    <swe:location>
      <swe:Vector gml:id="STATION_LOCATION">
      <swe:coordinate name="easting">
        <swe:Quantity>
        <swe:uom code="degree"/>
    <swe:value>12.99734</swe:value>
    </swe:Quantity>
      </swe:coordinate>
    <swe:coordinate name="northing">
      <swe:Quantity>
    <swe:uom code="degree"/>
    <swe:value>47.79367</swe:value>
    </swe:Quantity>
    </swe:coordinate>
    <swe:coordinate name="altitude">
      <swe:Quantity>
    <swe:uom code="m"/>
    <swe:value>433</swe:value>
    </swe:Quantity>
    </swe:coordinate>
    </swe:Vector>
    </swe:location>
    </swe:Position>
    </sml:position>
    <sml:inputs>
    <sml:InputList>
      <sml:input name="position">
        <swe:ObservableProperty definition="urn:ogc:def:phenomenon:OGC:1.0.30:position"/>
      </sml:input>
      </sml:InputList>
    </sml:inputs>

    <sml:outputs>
    <sml:OutputList>
      <sml:output name="position">
    <swe:Quantity definition="urn:ogc:def:phenomenon:OGC:1.0.30:position">
    <gml:metaDataProperty>
      <offering>
        <id>position</id>
      <name>Tracking Position Cartesian, in 2D</name>
      </offering>
      </gml:metaDataProperty>
      <swe:uom code="m"/>
    </swe:Quantity>
    </sml:output>

    <sml:output name="altitude">
    <swe:Quantity definition="urn:ogc:def:property:OGC:AltitudeAboveMSL">
      <gml:metaDataProperty>
        <offering>
        <id>altitude</id>
        <name>Altitude above Mean Sea Level</name>
        </offering>
      </gml:metaDataProperty>
      <swe:uom code="m"/>
    </swe:Quantity>
    </sml:output>

    <sml:output name="convell_a">
      <swe:Quantity definition="urn:ogc:def:property:OGC:conva">
        <gml:metaDataProperty>
          <offering>
          <id>convell_a</id>
          <name>Convidence Ellipse Semiaxis a</name>
          </offering>
        </gml:metaDataProperty>
        <swe:uom code="m"/>
      </swe:Quantity>
    </sml:output>

    <sml:output name="convell_b">
    <swe:Quantity definition="urn:ogc:def:property:OGC:convb">
      <gml:metaDataProperty>
      <offering>
    <id>convell_b</id>
        <name>Convidence Ellipse Semiaxis b</name>
    </offering>
      </gml:metaDataProperty>
    <swe:uom code="m"/>
    </swe:Quantity>
    </sml:output>

    <sml:output name="convell_phi">
    <swe:Quantity definition="urn:ogc:def:property:OGC:convphi">
      <gml:metaDataProperty><offering>
        <id>convell_phi</id>
        <name>Convidence Ellipse Angle Phi</name>
        </offering>
      </gml:metaDataProperty>
      <swe:uom code="m"/>
    </swe:Quantity>
    </sml:output>

    </sml:OutputList>
    </sml:outputs>

    <sml:components>
    <sml:ComponentList>
          <sml:component name="sensorsystem"><sml:Component>
          <sml:identification>
            <sml:IdentifierList>
        <sml:identifier>
          <sml:Term definition="urn:ogc:def:identifier:OGC:uniqueID">
        <sml:value>urn:ogc:object:feature:Sensor:TUWSystem</sml:value>
        </sml:Term>
        </sml:identifier>
        </sml:IdentifierList>
        </sml:identification>

        <sml:inputs>
        <sml:InputList>
          <sml:input name="position">
          <swe:ObservableProperty definition="urn:ogc:def:phenomenon:OGC:1.0.30:position"/>
          </sml:input>
        </sml:InputList>
        </sml:inputs>

        <sml:outputs>
        <sml:OutputList>
          <sml:output name="position">
          <swe:Quantity definition="urn:ogc:def:phenomenon:OGC:1.0.30:position">
        <gml:metaDataProperty>
      <offering>
          <id>position</id>
          <name>Tracking Position Cartesian, in 2D</name>
          </offering>
            </gml:metaDataProperty>
        <swe:uom code="m"/>
        </swe:Quantity>
        </sml:output>

        <sml:output name="altitude">
          <swe:Quantity definition="urn:ogc:def:property:OGC:AltitudeAboveMSL">
          <gml:metaDataProperty>
            <offering>
            <id>altitude</id>
            <name>Altitude above Mean Sea Level</name>
            </offering>
          </gml:metaDataProperty>
          <swe:uom code="m"/>
          </swe:Quantity>
        </sml:output>

        <sml:output name="convell_a">
          <swe:Quantity definition="urn:ogc:def:property:OGC:conva">
        <gml:metaDataProperty>
          <offering>
          <id>convell_a</id>
          <name>Convidence Ellipse Semiaxis a</name>
        </offering>
            </gml:metaDataProperty>
        <swe:uom code="m"/>
          </swe:Quantity>
        </sml:output>

        <sml:output name="convell_b">
        <swe:Quantity definition="urn:ogc:def:property:OGC:convb">
          <gml:metaDataProperty>
        <offering>
        <id>convell_b</id>
        <name>Convidence Ellipse Semiaxis b</name>
            </offering>
        </gml:metaDataProperty>
        <swe:uom code="m"/>
        </swe:Quantity>
        </sml:output>

        <sml:output name="convell_phi">
        <swe:Quantity definition="urn:ogc:def:property:OGC:convphi">
          <gml:metaDataProperty>
            <offering>
        <id>convell_phi</id>
            <name>Convidence Ellipse Angle Phi</name>
            </offering>
          </gml:metaDataProperty>
          <swe:uom code="m"/>
        </swe:Quantity>
        </sml:output>
        </sml:OutputList>
        </sml:outputs>

        </sml:Component>
        </sml:component>
        </sml:ComponentList>
        </sml:components>
        </sml:System>
        </sml:member>
        </sml:SensorML>
      </SensorDescription>

      <ObservationTemplate>
      <om:Measurement>
        <om:samplingTime/>
        <om:procedure/>
        <om:observedProperty/>
        <om:featureOfInterest>
        </om:featureOfInterest>
        <om:result uom="">
        </om:result>
        </om:Measurement>
      </ObservationTemplate>
    </RegisterSensor>
```

The exception Response i get from the server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/1.1.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidRequest" locator="REQUEST">
  <ows:ExceptionText>The GET request null is not supported by this SOS.
</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

The Java Code:

```
public class HttpRequest 
            extends Thread {
            private String url = "http://giv-sos.uni-muenster.de:8080/52nSOSv3/sos";
            private String charset = "UTF-8";
            private String xml_request;                 //request to db in xml format

            private URLConnection connection;
            private OutputStream output;
            private InputStream input;
            private String query;                       //transformed xml request

            /** Ctor.
             * @param xml ogc request as String
             */
            HttpRequest(String xml) {
                this.xml_request = xml;
            }

            //thread 
            public void run() {
                // converting String xml to application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME format
                try {
                    query = URLEncoder.encode(xml_request, charset);        //transforms special chars
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                }

        System.out.println("REQUEST: "+xml_request.toString());

                // create connection
                try {
                    connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
        System.out.println("CONNECTION: "+connection. toString());

                    connection.setDoOutput(true);                           //true = set method to POST
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset="+charset);

                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    System.out.println("MalformedURLException: " + ex.toString());
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("IOException: " + ex.toString());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.toString());
                }

                // open connection link
                try {
                    connection.connect();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.toString());
                }

                try {
                    //write outputstream to server
                    output = connection.getOutputStream();
                    output.write(query.getBytes(charset));

                    //read response from server
                    input = new URL(url).openStream();
                    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(input);
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;

                    //read
                    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                        response.append(line+"\n");

        System.out.println("RESPONSE: "+response.toString());

                    //close reader
                    bufferedReader.close();


                    // close stream
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (output != null)
                        try {
                            output.close();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            System.out.println("IOEXCEPTION: "+ex.toString());
                        }
                }

            }
        }
```

The exceptionCode="InvalidRequest" is pretty obvious, but still confuse me that i can't find and clue of it in the doku....

I am happy about every answer!

Comment: Is there no one who has an idea???

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty simple. You are mixing the GET (in the OGC docs these are called KVP or Key Value Pair) and SOAP interfaces of the server. So you can get the capabilities of the server using KVP doing something like this:

```
http://giv-sos.uni-muenster.de:8080/52nSOSv3?service=SOS&version=1.0.0&request=getCapabilities
```

But normally to register a sensor, you must have administration permission and be able to use the SOAP protocol to include the full XML document describing the sensor. This means that you have wrapped the RegisterSensor XML in the SOAP envelope like so (pretend this is RegisterSensor and not GetCapabilities, I'm being terse here). Note also that service/version is the same as above, but the request parameter is now the tag:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding" xmlns:sos="http://www.opengis.net/sos/1.0">
  <soap:Header />
  <soap:Body>
    <ns:GetCapabilities service="SOS" version="1.0.0" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Try this GetCapabilities request on your favorite SOS SOAP server and see if you don't get a capabilities document back.